# const unsigned char ptr (UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>) to String

Tags: swift

I'm trying to work with libxml directly in Swift. Now I want to get a `const unsigned char *` to a String, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

In Objective-C it works with

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)nodePointer->name];
```

Comment: You can use that method, and then simply assign it to a Swift `String` and it will be cast for you!

Comment: I already tried `let str: String = NSString(UTF8String: nodePointer.memory.name)`. Doesn't work!

Comment: try `let str: String = NSString(UTF8String: nodePointer.memory.name) as String`

Comment: I ran into this with sqlite3, where some strings are defined as `const unsigned char *` and wound up having to maul the header to change them to `const char*` in the header.  Be interesting to see if anybody has a better solution.

Comment: @JackWu: Doesn't work either.

Comment: @David: That's really not a good solution (and as well not possible for integrated libraries like libxml). Hmmm....

Comment: I completely agree. which is why it's a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: It's possible for libxml as well, just copy the header files into your local project and modify them there.  It's ugly as hell, but it is possible and it does work.  And I haven't seen a better answer yet.

Comment: Also not a great solution, but you could migrate to using `NSXMLParser` instead of `libxml`.

Comment: Or put a thin C and/or Objective-C layer in between libxml and swift.

Comment: No, NSXMLParser is much slower and the handling is not very easy I think. I already have an objective-c layer for libxml which I want to translate to Swift. Using it directly is slower because of the briding.

Comment: `stringWithUTF8String:` is a class method, not a custom initializer right? so instead of the new omitting thru 'with' syntax, does `NSString.stringWithUTF8String(...)` work?

Comment: Also, do you need an NSString, or can you use a Swift String? Swift's string class has a `fromCString` method that worked like a charm for me.

Comment: No :( `Can't convert the expression's type 'NSString!' to type '$T7'

Comment: String.fromCString doesn't work either :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
let cString = CString(nodePointer.name)
let string = String.fromCString(cString)
```

That worked for me when dealing with a string value which was returned as an `UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>` when nothing else would work.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! But "->" doesn't work anymore in Swift. Necessary was `nodePointer.memory.name`. Maybe you can change it in your answer. BIG THX !

Comment: Any idea how to go the way back from Swift String to CConstPointer<CUnsignedChar>? ;)

Comment: My bad - I was just typing looking at your code and should have noticed that I was typing the wrong thing :)

Comment: Regarding converting from Swift String to CConstPointer<CUnsignedChar>, have you tried, str.bridgeToObjective().cString() wehre str is the Swift string?

Comment: Does not work ('CString is not convertible to CConstPointer<CUnsignedChar>') :( One thing to your answer: Right way is `nodePointer.memory.name`. If I understand it right, you need "memory" to access the value "behind" the pointer

Comment: Since I have no idea what type/class `nodePointer`is, I was giving a general answer that you'd need to modify to suit your class/type :) Actually, I just realized that you'd mentioned you were working with libXML, but still, it was a generic answer ...